# Ruby - Tell user what stage of the day and season of the year (Use Hash)

Tags: ruby, loops, hash, key-value

I have a question for the following challenge.

### 1) Tell the user what season of the year it is. Condition is I need to use hash.

- What I want to to loop seasons and find an element that is equivalent to current_month which is 10. Then extract its key, spring.  Could you give me a clue on how I should modify my current .map method?

### 2) Tell the user what stage of the day (morning, noon, afternoon, evening, nighttime, midnight). (Use hash)

- What I want is to compare current hour of the day value and get key of the corresponding value.
- I have created the hour ranges. Is there any other way to create them?

Thanks!

```
current_month = Time.now.month
current_day = Time.now.yday 
current_hour_of_day = Time.now.hour 

seasons = {"spring" => [9,10,11],
    "summer" => [12,1,2], 
    "autumn" => [3,4,5],
    "winter" => [6,7,8]
    }

current_season = seasons.map do |k,v|
    if seasons[v].include?(current_season)
    puts "It is #{seasons[k]}." 
    end 
end 



current_hour_of_day = Time.now.hour 
day_stage = {"morning" => current_hour_of_day >= 6 && current_hour_of_day <= 12,
    "noon" => current_hour_of_day > 12 && current_hour_of_day <= 14,
    "afternoon" => current_hour_of_day >= 18 && current_hour_of_day <= 20,
    "evening" =>  current_hour_of_day >= 18 && current_hour_of_day <= 20, 
    "nighttime" => current_hour_of_day >= 21 && current_hour_of_day <= 23,
    "midnight" => current_hour_of_day == 24
    }

day_stage.each do |stg, hr|
    if hr === Time.now.strftime('%B') 
        puts "It is #{day_stage[stg]}"
    end 
end 

puts day_stage
```

Comment: Inside your `do` block, you use the variable `current_season`, but you set this variable AFTER the `map` has finished. Hence, it will always be `nil` inside the block. And after the `map` has ended, `current_season` will be set to an array of the return values of your `puts` statement.  Since `puts` returns `nil`, `current_season` will be set to an array of `nil` values.

Comment: Thanks! I now understand why I have { } empty output. :)

Comment: I understand that in Sidney, NSW, the summer solstice begins on Sunday, December 22, 2019 at 3:19 pm AEDT.  Therefore, if you are asked what season it is at breakfast that day you would say, "spring", but if asked at dinner you would reply, "summer". I expect you are being asked,  in part 1, "What season is it, *at this very moment*?", not "...this month". It makes no sense to ask what season it is in December.

Comment: Thanks @CarySwoveland. My tutor said this challenge is to build up students' coding skill. Some of them do not make sense to me either. I need to practice the given challenges and tackle the upcoming assignment - Terminal app :)

Answer (score 2):

You are using hash wrong. Hash is a tool/type which provides possibility to effectively find value based on the key.
If you are looping hash, then you don't need to use hash, but collection (array, enumerable or set)

Because amount of months and hours in day are limited and their values are unique you can use it as a key and season or stage of the day as value.

```
months = {
    1 => "summer",
    2 => "summer",
    3 => "autumn",
    4 => "autumn",
    5 => "autumn",
    6 => "winter",
    7 => "winter",
    8 => "winter",
    9 => "spring",
    10 => "spring",
    11 => "spring",
    12 => "summer",
}
```

Then finding current season will be O(1) operation within one line of code

```
current_season = seasons[current_month]
```

Comment: Thanks Fabio! This makes me realised that I better read and review data types particularly hash.

Comment: In this approach, summer is repeated three times so are winter, etc. I have learnt about DRY principle a few weeks ago. In this case, does this var_moth not comply with DRY principle? Thanks!

Comment: @FuriousCodeNinja yes, I would not consider this DRY. I would create a method rather than a hash and use a `case` with Ranges so you can specify that `3..5` all return "autumn". But if you _must_ use a hash, this is an OK approach.

Comment: You can always save name into a variable and reuse it ;)

Comment: Thanks @Max and @Fabio! :) I am now learning methods, blocks, enumerable and classes. I will attempt this challenge again in mid next week and will update this. Thanks!